# Add a data row in google charts after rendering

Tags: charts, google-visualization

Is it possible to add a line into a Line Chart after the Chart has been loaded? Something like

> chart.addRows(...)

I want to add those new lines after clicking a dom element.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, and then you have to redraw your chart to update in accordance to your changes.